# Error on bulidtime when running Vungle in spritekit app

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit, vungle-ads

So, I open up my xcode project today and tried to run it on my iphone 6s as I usually do without any problems but when I did it, it gave me these errors I have Vungle installed and from memory I was able to run it fine but now its giving me this. I also have chartboost installed in my app and followed Vungle's install instructions perfectly so i don't know why its giving me these errors. Why is it doing this?

[image]

Comment: I know this sounds awful, but try making a new project then porting everything over. If the error goes away then it was likely a bug in Xcode or your frameworks.

Comment: I found out that the other linker file was set to -ObjC and not to -lz but now when I switch them it asks me to put it back into -ObjC in the console instead of -lz because it cant find the adapter frameworks when trying to use mediation for chartboost and Vungle together through adMob